# ConcRT synchronization structures vs Standard Library

Tags: c++, c++11, concurrency-runtime

If my application targets Windows and already uses Concurrency Runtime in some of it's parts. Is there any advantages/disadvantages of using ConcRT synchronization structures (`concurrency:critical_section`) over standard library implementation (`std::mutex`) outside of ConcRT tasks? (e.g. Synchronizing WinAPI async callbacks or managing data access between exported functions of dll)

MSDN documentation of `<mutex>` states that it is based on ConcRT, but does it mean that internally mutex uses critical_section and therefore slower in all situations, thus gives advantage only in portability?
Or, conversely, critical_section is designed specifically for using with ConcRT scheduler and is a huge overkill, when used with OS threads?

P.S. This question concerns all sync structures in Concurrency Runtime (critical_section, reader_writer_lock & event).
Also I left out WinAPI's `CRITICAL_SECTION`, `MUTEX`, `SRW` and other, assuming them as the fastest and lightest solutions (but not prettiest).

Comment: "*therefore slower in all situations*" What makes that necessary? Just because it's an abstraction doesn't mean that it's slower.

Comment: I assumed it as possible reason it could be slower. Also, as you stated, I have not found any proof of this.

Answer (score 1):

I had to change my std:mutex to concurrency::critical_section because it actually behaves differently: when a mutex blocks it simply blocks, when a critical_section blocks ConcRT will start/reuse a new thread (if available). In my case I lost a lot of parallelism due to this difference before I made the switch.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff601929.aspx, "Use Cooperative Synchronization Constructs When Possible"

Comment: But does it's "cooperative threading model" apply to OS threads or it works only with "tasks"? Also consider the situation where blocked threads are produced outside of your code (e.g. when your code in dll is called from multithreaded process, and you want to lock it's access to single resource)